# PHP session for once only advert

Tags: php, session-variables

I want an advert to show just once. I've tried lots of JQuery ones on here and seem to fail to get them to work also. I've used PHP $_SESSION variables elsewhere so I though this would be an easy answer...

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["visit"] !== "visited") {
  echo '<div class="container fullwidth" id="mobileAppAd">';
  /* rest of div */ 
  echo '<button onClick="closeAd()" id="closeAd" class="btn  btnmain">X</button>';
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  $_SESSION["visit"] = "visited";
}
?>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Seems like a cookie would be better. Sessions are temporary.

Comment: I want for just the session, not sure why you think I cookie is better? @wogsland the bracket was just missed off here. It's there and still doesn't work.

Comment: I thought you just wanted it to show once forever, not just the session.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["visit"]) || $_SESSION["visit"] !== "visited") {
```

Because the **visit** index will not be set when you first initialize the session

Comment: If the index isn't set, `$_SESSION["visit"]` will be null, so it's not equal to `visited`. There will be a warning about the undefined index, but the test will still work.

Comment: YES! Thank you works. This will only show the banner once per user session. I would like it to be there until they close it. I tried adding an onclick event to the close to run the following:

`function setvisited() {
    $.get("visited.php");
 $("#mobileAppAd").hide();
 return false; 
}`

The visited script just contains the `$_SESSION["visit"] = "visited";` line but it doesn't run the PHP. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stu The button's `onclick` attribute call the `closeAd()` function, but the function name in your previous commentis `setvisited()`

Comment: Yes sorry I changed it. The JS is called by the onclick event as the ad is hidden. However it doesn't call the PHP session so the $_SESSION variable is not set and the ad just reappears on page reload.

Comment: @Stu - If your script only contain the `$_SESSION["visit"] = "visited";` line, is must also contain `session_start();` before you try to store anything in the session

Comment: YES! Well spotted @Alon ! Thank you all works perfectly now :-)

Comment: @Stu - Great! Glad I was able to help